# APDU Command Error - response 6C6B

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I am trying to read smart card using PCSC commands in Objective-C.

```
  int count = 17;
unsigned char *get_cplc_command = (unsigned char *)calloc(count, sizeof(unsigned char));
get_cplc_command[1]=-92;
get_cplc_command[2]=4;
get_cplc_command[4]=12;
get_cplc_command[5]=-96;
get_cplc_command[8]=2;
get_cplc_command[9]=67;
get_cplc_command[11]=19;
get_cplc_command[15]=1;
get_cplc_command[16]=1;

receive_length = sizeof(receive_buffer);

ret = SCardTransmit(card, 
                    &sendPCI,
                    get_cplc_command, 
                    sizeof(get_cplc_command),
                    NULL,
                    receive_buffer,
                    &receive_length);

LOG(@"SCardTransmit 0x%08x", ret);
```

When I execute above command I am getting 6C6B response.  Can you please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The status word `6CXX` means, that the `Le` field of the command APDU was wrong.

Citing ISO 7816-3, Table 14:

> Process aborted due to a wrong Le field (SW2 encodes Na, i.e., the
>   exact number of available data bytes). In cases 1 and 3,  the card
>   should not use such a value. In cases 2 and 4, the card shall be ready
>   to receive the same command with P3 =  SW2.

And ISO 7816-4, Section 5.1.3:

> If SW1 is set to '6C', then the process is aborted and
>   before issuing any other command, the same 
>   command may be re-issued using SW2 (exact number of available data bytes) as short Le field.

---

(Although not familiar with Objective-C) My bet is that the 4th argument of `SCardTransmit` (i.e. `sizeof(get_cplc_command)`) should be `count` instead -- as the `sizeof` operator does not give you the size of allocated array, but the size of the pointer to it.

[Presuming 32-bit architecture and `sizeof(unsigned char*)` equal to `4`]: Command sent was not `00A404000CA00000024300130000000101` as intended, but `00A40400` which was interpreted as case 1 command (see ISO 7816-3, Section 12.1.2 for command APDU cases description).

Good luck!

---

PS: Please consider checking your `receive_length` variable for the same problem.

---

EDIT> Regarding the `61XX` status:

As @guidot wrote, you need to issue a GET RESPONSE (another command) to get the response data immediately after receiving this status word.

Citing ISO 7816-4:

> If SW1 is set to '61', then the process is completed and before
>   issuing any other command, a GET RESPONSE command may be issued with
>   the same CLA and using SW2 (number of data bytes still available)  as
>   short Le field.

The above-mentioned `GET RESPONSE` command is documented in ISO 7816-4 as well (see e.g. [here](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_7_transmission_interindustry_commands.aspx#chap7_1)).

In your case the APDU exchange should probably look like this:

```
> 00A404000CA00000024300130000000101 // SELECT command
< 6121 // SELECT response -- 33 bytes still available
> 00C0000021 // GET RESPONSE command
< XXXX...XX9000 // GET RESPONSE response (33 bytes and a status word)
```

(You will have to call the `SCardTransmit` twice, once for `00A404000C...` and then for `00C0000021...`. Remember to reset the `receive_length` variable if re-used).

---

Note: You might want to try sending a `00A404000CA0000002430013000000010100` command APDU (the same command with a Le field present and set to 0x00 -- meaning you are expecting up to 256 bytes in the response data).

Comment: @vip, thank you for your response.  Now I have sent command as   unsigned char get_cplc_command[] = {0x00, 0xA4, 0x04, 0x00, 0x0C, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x43, 0x00, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01};  Now the response is 6121.  I tried to change sizeof for the 4th argument, it gives me compatibility error.  If response code 6121, please tell me how to rectify this.

Comment: @SaiKiran: This should be a separate question. Short answer nevertheless: command worked correctly, you have a T=0 card and need to send GET RESPONSE to retrieve the answer. I recommend to make yourself familiar with ISO 7816-3 and ISO 7816-4.

Comment: @SaiKiran I updated the answer. The compatibility error is strange, it should be possible to cast `int` to `DWORD` without problems....Probably sort of Objective-C speciality. Good luck!

Comment: @guidot  thanks for your response.  I am going through ISO references as well.

Comment: @vip,  it is really helping me your detailed response.  I will try along with Le field.

Comment: @vip, GET RESPONSE is working fine, able to get success response.  As per your suggestion tried with Le field 0x00 but invalid card status returned.

Comment: @SaiKiran Glad to hear that. (AFAIK) The variant with Le would spare you from using the GET RESPONSE if card was using the T=1 protocol. Good luck with your project!

Comment: @vip; Thank you.  I need your help as I am not able to move forward with project.